# Substitute username in Windows directory path with variable user ID

Tags: windows, ansible

I have a playbook that will possibly be run by multiple users. The playbook runs a batch script that was created by our auditing department. We are not allowed to modify the script in any way. Their script gets various information about the server and outputs it to a folder inside the users "Documents" folder. My objective is to create an Ansible playbook that can be run by anyone from the audit team that will

1. Remove the old audit data
2. Run the batch script
3. Archive the folder
4. Download the archived folder

I currently have the following tasks created:

```
---
- name: Remove old audit data
  win_file:
     path=C:\Users\my-username\Documents\PCI-Audit-Evidence
     state=absent

- name: Run audit check
  script: ../files/Windows-2008-2012-PCI.cmd

- name: Archive audit folder for download
  script: ../files/zipfolder.ps1

- name: Download audit file
  fetch:
     dest: "audits/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"
     src: "C:/Users/my-username/Documents/PCI-Audit-Evidence.zip"
     flat: yes
```

Everything works without issue. My problem is that I have hard-coded my username into the source fields of both the 1st and last task. I need "my-username" to be a variable that changes based on who runs the playbook. I have tried using the windows environment variable "$env:username", but that does not work. I have also tried "{{ ansible_user_id }} but after reviewing the facts for a Windows 2008 server, ansible does not actually log the username as a fact.

The only thing I can think of is to add another task that runs a script to login to the server and run a whoami or something and then register it as a variable but that seems overly complicated.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Note: I need the username to be from the remote system.

Also, how do I make it so fetch file with overwrite the file on the local machine if it already exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `USERPROFILE` (or `USERNAME` to strictly answer the question):

```
- name: Remove old audit data
  win_file:
     path: "{{ ansible_env.USERPROFILE }}\Documents\PCI-Audit-Evidence"
     state: absent
```

```
- name: Download audit file
  fetch:
     dest: "audits/{{ inventory_hostname }}/"
     src: "{{ ansible_env.USERPROFILE }}\Documents\PCI-Audit-Evidence.zip"
     flat: yes
```